# rviz goal topic: fuerte vs groovy

Tags: ros, rviz, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did the default **2D Nav Goal** topic advertised by rviz change from fuerte to groovy? It appears the new default is `move_base_simple/goal`, and the old one was just `goal`.

Is this intentional? I think it's cleaner if the default topic is just the generic `goal`, and the user can remap this using launch files, or vcg files. It seems the change broke our launch files between fuerte and groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56773/rviz-goal-topic:-fuerte-vs-groovy/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues for bug reports.

The next release of RViz will have this fixed.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-03-05**:
Thanks. Wasn't sure if bug or user error.